# MySQL table: How can I remove specific characters from all fields?

Tags: mysql, replace, schema

Every week, I have to completely replace the data in several very large MySQL tables. So what I normally do is delete the existing data, import the new data, and then run my usual queries to modify the new data as needed.

Unfortunately, these days I have noticed that the new data contains unwanted characters, such as quotes and extra spaces. With well over 100,000 records in some of these tables (AFAIK), I cannot easily open the data in notepad to strip out unwanted characters, prior to importing.

I realize I could write a separate find and replace query for every single column in every table, like this:

```
UPDATE mytablename SET mycolumn = REPLACE(mycolumn, '"', '');
```

But having to name every column is a bother. Anyway, I would like to find a more elegant solution. Today, I found a snippet on the internet that looks like a start:

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
        table_name = 'myTable' and ordinal_position = 1
```

I think the next step might be to loop through the ordinal positions, and then replace and update each column, but I don't know how to do this in MySQL. I also don't know how to stop the loop after the last column is reached, to avoid error messages.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or am I hoping for too much?

I am a beginner, so a clear, simple explanation would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

MORE INFORMATION:

1. Since my first post, I have discovered that stored procedures are not allowed on my server. Too bad.
2. Anyway, I have tried this new code, just to get started:

set @mytablestring='mytable';

set @mycolumnnumber=1;

set @mycolumnname=(SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = @mytablestring and ordinal_position = @mycolumnnumber);

SELECT @mycolumnname FROM mytable;

Unfortunately, in the final SELECT query, @mycolumnname is interpreted as a string, not as a column name. So the query does not work. If I could get past this, I believe I could  write some code to loop through the columns by incrementing @mycolumnnumber.

If anyone knows how to solve this, I would really appreciate some help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just assemble a script or write a procedure of SQL statements that clean the data?

Comment: Yes, there is a very good reason: I don't know how. Of course, I could write 100 or more separate queries to update the individual columns, but I am hoping there is a better solution, where a single query could search the whole table. There are quite a few posts asking this question on various forums, but I have never seen it answered in simple terms, without resorting to a text editor, and without having to write a separate query for each column. So I am curious to know whether MySQL is versatile and powerful enough to handle this kind of thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at vim, sed, awk and many of the other text editors and text processing utilities that you can find on Linux (and sometimes on Windows too). 100,000 records may be a pain in Notepad, but it's a piece of cake for *real* text processing utilities.

For example, to strip all `#` characters from `foobar.txt`:

```
sed 's/#//g' foobar.txt > foobar-clean.txt
```

Or, the same thing with the file opened in (g)vim:

```
:%s/#//g
```

Comment: That's very interesting and helpful. Thanks. 

However, using a text editor would still require extra steps, and I would really like to streamline this process. As well, I am curious to know whether MySQL can handle this kind of thing.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?